# Dubious Binomial Residuals

Tags: regression, binomial-distribution, residuals

In brief, I have a dataset that has dubious residuals, can anyone help me diagnose them, and maybe find a better modeling solution, or just general advice?

The data has 8,419,694 rows and 5 columns. The R commands to generate the model is

```
form <- formula(cbind(success,failure) ~ log(Q1+1)*log(Q2+1) + control)
m <- glm(form, data = df, family=binomial())
```

Q1 and Q2 are integers (designating Quality 1 and Quality 2) from 0 to 30ish. I fit the model and then after examining the residuals ended up removing 5 outliers and refit, in order to focus in on central tendency.

The residual plots are below:

[image: Residual vs Fitted]
[image: Residual vs Control]
[image: Residual vs Q1]
[image: Residual vs Q2]

They exhibit heteroskedasticity. I could use the R package [sandwich](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sandwich/sandwich.pdf), to make heteroscedasticity-robust standard errors. Is this enough, is there another other model I could use? I tried a beta_binomial model from brms, and it didn't help.

Any recommendations or general advice? Is there something I am missing or doing the binomial regression residuals wrong somehow? Thank you for your help!

Comment: try  `form <- formula(cbind(success, success+failure) ~ ...)`  instead of `form <- formula(cbind(success,failure)  ~ ...)`  - does the problem persist?

Comment: It's almost exactly the same. The reason is that success is a rare event, so failure is not that far different from success+failure. Do you think maybe I should just drop the failure column completely and model it as a count model? I would do this, but N is not random, summary(lm(N~control)) is highly significant.

Comment: There is likely a maximum value of the fraction which causes the cut-off. You can see this better in a plot of estimate vs observed (instead of estimate vs residuals)

Comment: Another effect, asside from heteroscedasticity, is that your model seems to be a misfit. You see an upward trend in the residuals. How can this happen? This can happen because of the big bulge of data points with smaller values that dominate the fit.

Comment: Estimate vs Observed https://imgur.com/uUb7IWm. I think I am going to make another post with the whole scenario, I was trying to make a MVE.

Answer (score 3):

The binomial distribution has variance $np(1-p)$. Therefore, the variance is dependent on the mean.

The reason why in usual linear regression, that we look for heteroscedasticity, is because the underlying model assumes that the residual Gaussian error is independent of the mean. This is not the case for a binomial GLM.

I suggest using something like the [`DHARMa` package in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html) to assess quality of a non-Gaussian GLM.

Comment: This is a good point, but may not need to be the case. In the image we see a decreasing variance for increasing valies, which may not be explained with the values of $p(1-p)$. Possibly it can be due to a larger number $n$ if that correlates with $p$.

Comment: Here is log(fitted) by log(N), as log(N) increases, log(fitted) decreases. I chose the log - log scale because the transformed scale was harder to interpret. https://imgur.com/Bi4wnmY

@alex-j  are you saying that heteroscedasity may not be a problem in binomial regression?

Comment: Heteroscedasticity is not a problem in binomial regression - the variance _will_ change as it is a function of $p$. however, there can be over/under dispersion issues, where the variance is not fully explained by the value of $p$

Answer (score 1):

An interesting property of binary data is, that it has to be Bernoulli distributed and so any misspecification in the model is a misspecification in the estimation of $p$. Perhaps a  complex one like a missing random effect, but that is still diagnosable in the means of the residuals. Sextus Empiricus had already alluded to that.

Anyway, you specifically fitted $\log (Q + 1)$ and when you plot against $Q$ you see that you consistently underestimated the observations(residuals $> 0$) when $Q$ is large. If we assume that the relationship with $Q$ is actually linear, within the of the logit-link, then we would see something just like that:

```r
# trying to roughly replicate your data
n <- 10^5 
x <- sample(0:50, size = n, prob = exp(-0.5*(0:50)), replace = T)
x[1] <- 40 # one outlier

# linear relationship
lin_pred <- 0.2*(x - 7)
n_s <- sample(10:20, size = n, replace = T) # just guessing on the sizes
success <- rbinom(n, size = n_s, prob = plogis(lin_pred)) # logit link
failure <- n_s - success

my_model <- glm(cbind(success, failure) ~ I(log(x + 1)), family = binomial())

plot(x, residuals(my_model))
```

[image]

So the first step should be to not do the log-transformation. With your amount of data the outlier $Q$-value is no concern.

Also `log(Q1+1)*log(Q2+1)` is both very hard to understand/justify and very restrictive. If you dislike simple linear effects I would recommend something like `gam` or another regularized spline fitting. With 8 million rows it barely has to be regularized at all.

Comment: I log transformed because I thought that the resid vs fitted looked better, but reevaluating it really doesn't specifically considering your points here. I think I am going to make another post with the whole scenario in more detail, I was trying to make MVE.